# Check if table is filtered

Tags: datatables, yadcf

is it possible with YADCF to do something like:

```
yadcf.exGetColumnFilterVal(oTable, 'all')
```

So it returns an array of values of all columns where a filter is applied?

I need to check if there is any filter in any column, also if they are hidden by column visibility. exGetColumnFilterVal is doing the trick, but I would like to avoid something like:

```
  if (yadcf.exGetColumnFilterVal(oTable, 0) != '') { }
  if (yadcf.exGetColumnFilterVal(oTable, 2) != '') { } 
  if (yadcf.exGetColumnFilterVal(oTable, 3) != '') { } 
  if (yadcf.exGetColumnFilterVal(oTable, 6) != '') { } 
  ...
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible, you can do a loop over your columns and inside it dom something like this

`if (yadcf.exGetColumnFilterVal(oTable, index) !== '') { }`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried with such a each loop, but then I come into this issue,: https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues/348
because I don't have filters enabled in all columns.

Comment: Then just check if there is a filter defined for that column (you can use a map/object to hold that kind of meta data about your table) before calling the `yadcf.exGetColumnFilterVal`